# XPath for element with child X with no leading text, and no child Y

Tags: html, xml, xpath

With this:

```
<p>Some variable length text <abbr>abc</abbr> and more text.</p>
<p><abbr>abc</abbr>Some variable length text.</p>
<p><abbr>abc</abbr>Some variable length text. <a href="somelink">blah</a></p>
```

I'm trying to build an Xpath that will find p elements that:

1. Have a child `<abbr>` with value of "abc", but that child has *no* intervening text between the parent and the child.
2. Does not have a child `<a>`.

#1 means the first line should not match, because it has text between the parent `<p>` and the child `<abbr>`.
#2 means the third line should not match, because although there is a child `<abbr>` and no leading text, it also has a child `<a>`.

Thus, only the second line,

```
<p><abbr>abc</abbr>Some variable length text.</p>
```

should match: no leading text, and no child `<a>`.

I've played with an XPath testbed for an hour, and done quite a bit of searching, but haven't figured out how to handle both of those requirements, but especially #1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//p[node()[1][self::abbr]='abc'][not(a)]
```

selects all `p` elements

1. with a first sibling `abbr` element that has a string value of `"abc"`<sup>1</sup>, and
2. without an `a` child,

as requested.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Note that #1 implies that `abbr` must be the first node, which prevents any node (text, another element, etc) from being a previous sibling to `abbr`.</sub>

Comment: Perfect. I clearly still have a long way to go before I "get" xpath. I can read that and understand what it does, but I would never have been able to come up with it.

Comment: @vr8ce: You'll get there.  XPath is wonderfully composable, so as learn more patterns you'll increasingly be able to create powerful new combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Try this XPath-1.0 expression:

```
//p[node()[1]!=text()[1] and abbr='abc' and not(a)]
```

It checks if the first child node is a `text()` node. Further checks are that it has a child "abbr" with the content 'abc' and no children named "a".